# Response message 404 - UCWA

Tags: azure, office365, skype-for-business, ucwa, autodiscovery

I am developing a skype Api to show user presence using ucwa with the help of steps outlined at [Authentication using Azure AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/skype/ucwa/AuthenticationUsingAzureAD).

I got the bearer token, but when I Perform a GET on the root resource with the bearer token, it always returns 404, Reason Phrase: not found. If I do not include token, it will return un-authorized. So, seems it authorized, but can not find the resource. what could cause this?

Comment: Hi Newbee,  can you provide the request URL that you are using?

Comment: Thanks for responding  John, URL is  **https://webdirXX.online.lync.com/oauth/user**. If I remove oauth/user from the URL, response message is 200 with no content. Thanks!